# If Else not working when used #!/bin/sh shebang in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I am using AIX 6.1. Below code is working fine for me.

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "host1" ]; then
  echo "This is host1"
elif [ "$HOSTNAME" = "host2" ]; then
  echo "This is host2"
else
  echo "This is another host"
fi
```

But when I use Shebang in my code, always the last else part is getting executed even if the first/second if conditions are true.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "host1" ]; then
  echo "This is host1"
elif [ "$HOSTNAME" = "host2" ]; then
  echo "This is host2"
else
  echo "This is another host"
fi
```

How can I get the same output as in first code snippet but with using shebang.

P.S. : I can't write the script without using shebang due to some constraints.

Comment: Which shell is your login shell? Is it the same one as /bin/sh ?
$> env | grep SHELL
Will tell you your shell if you are running a bash variant

Comment: env | grep SHELL gives SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh
And my bad, there is a space inside if condition. Edited the question

Comment: When using ksh, this page  suggests you need [[  ]] 
  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ksh-if-command-examples/amp/

Comment: Tried, but still goes to last else. Not understanding how does it work when I don't use shebang line.

Comment: When you don't use shebang, the currently running shell is used to evaluate the script. In your case ksh. Using the shebang tells your ksh shell that a different program is to be used to execute the contents, in this case /bin/sh.  Anyway, the question has been closed now. Good luck :-)

Comment: But its not duplicate question of the spaces before and after []

Comment: `HOSTNAME` is defined in bash, but /bin/sh isn't bash. Add this line into your script: `HOSTNAME="$(hostname)"`

Comment: @rohit 
Maybe if you edited the question and title to reflect the two different shells, and asked chepner they might reopen it for you?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond It worked like charm... Thank you :)

Comment: A a style point, and one which would immediately expose error, write this as `case ${HOSTNAME?HOSTNAME not defined} in host1) echo "this is host1";; host2) echo "this is host2";; *) echo another host;; esac`

Comment: Not directly related to the question -- just extra info.  AIX ships ksh, ksh93, and bsh.  "sh" is a link to one of those (I'm recalling this from memory so please verify).  bsh is the old Bourne shell.  But ksh called as "sh" has some Posix requirements (again... IIRC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lorinczy Zsigmond suggested, added `HOSTNAME="$(hostname)"` at the beginning of the script and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, different shells are being used in the two scenarios (some shells automatically create certain variables).

A kernel execing a script without a shebang should behave the same as if the script had the shebang `#!/bin/sh`, however, it appears that some shells, namely `bash`, `yash`, and `ksh` (possibly others) are cheating by interpreting the script directly in a forked-child instead of `execing` it.

id_shell:

```
if false; then :
elif [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then echo bash
elif [ -n "${KSH_VERSION:-}" ]; then echo ksh
elif [ -n "${POSH_VERSION:-}" ]; then echo posh
elif [ -n "${YASH_VERSION:-}" ]; then echo yash
elif [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]; then echo zsh
else
    echo sh;
fi
```

Test what shell is used to exec a shebang-less child script:

```
$ for sh in bash dash posh pdksh sh yash zsh ksh; do echo -n $sh: ; $sh -c './idself'; done

bash:bash
dash:sh
posh:sh
pdksh:sh
sh:sh
yash:yash
zsh:sh
ksh:ksh
```

To fix your particular issue, you could define `HOSTNAME` if it's not already defined:

```
: "${HOSTNAME:="$(hostname)"}"
```